# How can I make a Google map of all questions asked here?

Tags: support

Does TSE have an API, from where I can obtain tags, city names, countries, etc.?

The idea is to make a Google map to project all locations on which a question has been asked here.

If an API exists, has someone already made such a map?

Comment: http://stackapps.com

Comment: Maybe you can use [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com/travel%20answers/queries). Here you can compile a SQL query (if I understand correctly) to search the data of stackexchange sites. I just took a quick look and you can poll the `tag` and the `body` text of a post. I'm not familiar with SQL, but maybe if you are it should be possible to reach your goal (just guessing here). Good luck!

Comment: One tricky part is that there is no meta information to tell you which tags refer to places. I'm pretty familiar with the Stack Exchange API but not at all with the Google maps API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while it is based on Travel.SE data (locations etc.), this very specific question how to acquire and display the data *is not* on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an A, copying a Comment:

> [stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com/) – LessPop_MoreFizz Mar 6 '13 at 17:34

Regarding:

> If an API exists, has someone already made such a map?

Very probably not, where would a pin go for a question like this?:

[How can I deal with people asking to switch seats with me on a plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48775/how-can-i-deal-with-people-asking-to-switch-seats-with-me-on-a-plane)